# C++ reading in strings and characters

Tags: c++, string, input, output

Hi everyone I am working on a project for my CS class and I can't figure out how to read in part of my data file.

63f7hj-9 22spaces L Is this correct

My data file consists of this line of data and I have to figure out how to read in portions of it. I have to read in the 63 and save it as an integer and I do not need the f7hj-9. I also need to read in the 22spaces and save it as a string and the L as a character.

The phrase "Is this correct" needs to go into the console.

So my question is, how do I read in just the 63 and discard the rest of it?
Save the phrase "22 spaces" as a string. 
L as a character
And the phrase "Is this correct" as a string.

I am new to c++ and I have gotten parts of this project to work but I'm stuck on this part.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: look at std::regex

Comment: Read up on [lexing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) .

Comment: Hi Nick, What you need to do is try with what you have from the class and if you can not get your code to work, post that code with a specific question about what you don't understand.

Comment: @OznOg don't need regex here. We can do it using scanf as shown in the post below

Comment: @shirish I could probably accept the remark if you were at least checking errors from scanf. Not checking the return on such a parsing is more about wishful thinking than a solution...

Comment: @OznOg, actually I only thought about reading the input in the specified format. Now, modified the code for fscanf error check.

Answer (score 0):

Reading input from file and splitting the line

```
63f7hj-9                      L Is this correct
```

into integer as 63, ignoring 7hj-9 and then reading the 22 spaces in space1 string and then reading character L as a character and the rest of the string " Is this correct" inside the string str2.

This is an example of how you can use fscanf(or scanf) to achieve this.

- %d will read the integer as it is the format specifier for integer
- Next we need to ignore the "f7hj-9" from the file so just writing it as it is will do the job
- Next we need to read 22 spaces so %22c will read 22 characters irrespective of whether the character is a newline or space(here 22 spaces)
- Next we need to read a character so %c will store it in char c
- Now another %*c will ignore the one whitespace after L
- using %[^\n]s will read the rest of the string until newline

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int n;
  char c;
  char space1[23];
  char str2[32];
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("b.txt", "r");
  if(fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open the file\n");
    return 1;
  }
  if(fscanf(fp, "%df7hj-9%22c%c%*c%[^\n]s", &n, space1, &c, str2) != 4) {
      printf("Read failure\n");
      return 1;
  }
  printf("Integer = %d\n", n);
  printf("Spaces = %sEnd\n", space1);
  printf("Character = %c\n", c);
  printf("String = %s", str2);
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
63f7hj-9                      L Is this correct
```

Output:

```
Integer = 63
Spaces =                       End
Character = L
String = Is this correct
```

Comment: @Nick understood?